# Standards and best practices on response of Rest-API

Tags: rest, api, crud, endpoint

I am currently developing a Restful API, it involves the CRUD operations for some tables and also the Authentication endpoints. But now, I am wondering which are the best practices, the conventions of standards of what should be returned in the endpoints, basically I have this:

1. Create: returns the new created object
2. Read: returns the object that the user wants
3. Update: returns the object with the new values
4. Delete: return the object that has been deleted.

When the operation is successful I return status code 200, else I return error. Is it ok? what should I take in count?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see it correct, you should also return the corresponding http status code according to what happened in case of error. For instance:

**404**: Read, Delete. But no records found

**409**: Create, Update. But a conflict happened, maybe a constraint was violated, or you were trying to create a duplicated entry...

Here is a good [resource](http://parker0phil.com/2014/10/16/REST_http_4xx_status_codes_syntax_and_sematics/)